# Unit tests for interactive python program with behave

Tags: python, unit-testing, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I'm trying to write test cases for a python program with [behave](http://behave.readthedocs.org/en/latest) that expects input from Stdin.

I invoke it currently like this:

```
import my_script

@when('we run "{command}"')
def run(context, command):
    args = command.split()[1:]
    my_script.cli(args)
```

And `myscript.cli` takes args and parses them with `argparse`, and eventually has a line that says `value = raw_input("Make a choice"). This is where the behave tests stop and wait for input. I would like to give the input in my steps like this:

```
@when('we run "{command}" and enter "{text}"')
def run(context, command, text):
    ...
```

I suppose I will have to mock a stdin interface and make my script use that in the test cases, but I'm not sure what the most elegant way of doing with with behave is.

Answer (score 0):

[behave](https://github.com/behave/behave) uses a "behave4cmd0" for its self-tests (with behave). This contains a step definition @when('I run "{command}"'). You can register your command in "environment.py" and it will be called as subprocess.

"behave4cmd0" is currently lacking the feature you need to interact with a spawned subprocess (but this is planned for the future). The problem you can facing has little to do with behave. It is just a plain programming or Python problem. Look into the Python subprocess module or pyexpect. It should provide the features that you need.

You can also look into [aruba's interactive](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/master/features/interactive.feature) feature to see how your problem can be mapped to step definitions.